# How to remove both file extension and trailing slash with .htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I would like all possible URLs used to access my site to end up with a URL with no file extension and no trailing slash. Currently I have been able to solve the file extension issue, and the trailing slash issue separately, however if a URL with no file extension and a trailing slash is used it sends them to my 404 page, such as https://mysite/news/. This should end up as https://mysite/news and fetch the file news.php, but it redirects to my 404. Here is my current .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Redirect to domain without www.
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# 404 errors
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

# Remove file types
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# Remove trailing slashes
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s(.+?)/+[?\s]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: `I would like all possible URLs used to access my site to end up with a URL with no file extension and no trailing slash.` ok then only deliver url like that. I dont thing you have to remove (lets say repair) the url parts. *if* someone uses an extention (handwritten in the browser) direct him to 404.  Why repair / remove at all?

Comment: And give some more Examples, because there are to less information to help. Lets say you have an `news.php` that is called you redirect to `news`. At this point the question is witch PHP File gets the request? `news.php` or `index.php` or what? And if the file `news.php` exists, redircting makes no sence. Cant better explain it here. But you have to give way more information like  `who really handels the request?` Thing you should update you question, im out :)

Comment: Move your trailing slash removing rule above `ErrorDocument` line and clear browser cache.

Comment: @anubhava that worked! thanks, I had no idea the order of a .htaccess could effect it's behavior so much, thanks for the help

Comment: Though it is in working state now but it is redirecting 3 times if original URL is `http://www.example.com/news/` which is bad for both SEO ranking and user experience.

Comment: Is there a best practice for this then? Should I just leave the trailing slashes leading to 404 or something else?